# Give custom file name to p-table export

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng table in my angular application. I'm trying to assign append the export csv file with the current time when the user exports the table content. However the first time I export, the file name is not getting updated with time. The next time it works but the filename is appended with the previous time. My guess is that the export filename is using the older filename & not the updated one. Don't know why that's happening. I'm calling the setFile method when I do the export. It should take the updated file name. Please help.Thanks in advance.

Here is my template code:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" #dt [value]="students" [autoLayout]="true"  exportFilename={{testFileName}}>
        <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
            <div >
                <button  mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="setFileName();dt.exportCSV()" style="float:right"><mat-icon>save_alt</mat-icon></button>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

My typescript:

```
  students: any[];
  cols: any[];

  testFileName = 'SampleFile';
  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentService.getAllStudents().subscribe(data => this.students = data);

    this.cols = [
      { field: 'name', header: 'Name' },
      { field: 'rollNo', header: 'RollNo' },
      { field: 'class', header: 'Class' },
    ];
  }



setFileName() {
    this.testFileName = 'StudentDetailsExport' + '_' +
      new DatePipe('en-US').transform(Date.now(), 'MMM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss', 'UTC') + 'Z';

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the element reference

```
@ViewChild('dt') dt: Table;
```

and set filename using this.dt.exportFileName and then dt.exportCSV() to export.

```
setFileName() {
    this.dt.exportFileName = 'StudentDetailsExport' + '_' +
      new DatePipe('en-US').transform(Date.now(), 'MMM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss', 'UTC') + 'Z';
   this.dt.exportCSV();
  }
```

HTML - only call setFileName() function

```
<button  mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="setFileName()"></button>
```

Stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptable-io6vjb

Comment: uh its this.dt.nativeElement.exportCSV() ..and im creating stackblitz

Comment: Also what you're suggesting is the same that I'm doing by calling two methods. For what you suggested instead of ElementRef, i have to use Table & then call this.dt.exportCsv(). However the issue still remains

Comment: so did you test it using Table your method??

Comment: yeah I tested your approach with table, same issue

Comment: ok if you are able to get table inside setFileName() then use table.exportFileName='StudentDetailsExport' + '_' +
      new DatePipe('en-US').transform(Date.now(), 'MMM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss', 'UTC') + 'Z'; before doing exportCsv();

Comment: was about to try the same thing. It works. You can update your answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @wazza i updated the answer please check if its correct.

Comment: Just to add to your answer, the filename variable to overwrite is `exportFilename`, as opposed to `exportFileName` mentioned in your answer.